# Show all data from a sql table. (Angular)

Tags: angular

My problem is that I need to show all the entries of a sql table in Angular view.

I can already access the elements by ID, but I would like to press a button to show all.

```
<h3> Mostrar disco</h3>
¿Que disco quieres ver? <input #id><br>
<button type="button" (click) = "mostrarDisco(id.value)">Mostrar</button><br>
<hr>
<div *ngIf="disco!=null">
Titulo:{{disco.titulo}} <br>
Interprete:{{disco.interprete}} <br>
Año Publicacion:{{disco.anyoPublicacion}} <br>
<hr>
</div>
```

I know I have to use ngFor in the view but I don't know how to do it.

API query:

```
router.get('/discos', (req, res)=>{
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM discos', (err, rows, fields)=>{

    if(!err){
      res.json(rows);
    }else{
     console.log(err);
    }


})

});
```

Query discos by ID:

Service:

```
  getDisco(id:number)
  {
    return this.http.get(this.url + "/" + id)
  }
```

Component:

```
 mostrarDisco(id:number)


 {
    this.apiService.getDisco(id).subscribe((data) =>
  {
  this.disco = data[0]
  })  
  }
```

Help me please!

Comment: Can you please reproduce the same on stackblitz and share the link here

Comment: It is simple. I am already able to show the disks by ID, now I want to show all the disks in the table

Answer (score 0):

Suppose in your Component you have API call and save the JSON response to variable discos.

```
this.discos = json_response;
```

In your HTML you can have a div as below :

```
<div *ngIf="discos" **ngFor="let disco of discos">
Titulo:{{disco.titulo}} <br>
Interprete:{{disco.interprete}} <br>
Año Publicacion:{{disco.anyoPublicacion}}
</div>
```

I hope this should help.